# "This item could not be crawled because the crawler could not connect to the repository."

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

In the Error Breakdown in the Crawl Log - URL > Search Service Application, I am receiving an error for all SP sites I am attempting to Crawl

> "This item could not be crawled because the crawler could not connect to the repository."

I have already verified that the crawl account has access to the web applications and I am running SP 2013.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of things to check:

- try to browse the web application from the Crawl server, if you can access the site. Make sure their is no access bloackage.
- Make Sure Antivirus is not blocking that url
- make sure that loopback check is disable on the crawl server
- crawl account has access to the Web application
- try to increase the [timeout value](http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2014/05/issue-this-item-could-not-be-crawled.html) and also check the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks, Waqas! I cannot browse the web application from the Crawl server. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: It is either loop back check issue, disable it on crawl server or also check if firewall blocking it

Comment: loop back check on the crawl server was set to "1" so I have changed this to "0"